# Link popularity check

Tags: links

Where do i search to check link popularity for my site? On a different site i get different counts.

Besides, what is the difference if check for link popularity using `http://article-stack.com/` or `article-stack.com`?

In 2nd case it shows higher counts.

Comment: I didn't see any difference between `article-stack.com` and `http://article-stack.com` at Google or Yahoo ... where are you searching?

Comment: I am searching over the sites, dedicated to check link popularity only. like submitexpress.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query format really depends on the tool you are using to check the link popularity. Both Yahoo! and Google offer a way to get an accurate list of inbound link from their webmaster console.

Yahoo calls it [Site Explorer](https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/), Google offers [Google Webmasters Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools). With Google, you can also use the `link:` operator, but [it is known](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjQ2QVQpaK0) to offer an approximate number of results.

The most affordable tool in this area is probably [Majestic SEO](http://www.majesticseo.com/). It offers an accurate database of links you can search to get many interesting link analysis.